# find and sed (find and replace) causes illegal byte sequence on Mac OS X

Tags: shell, osx

I am attempting to perform a find and replace of underscores to dots in a directory for certain filetypes only (.mkv, .mp4, .avi). This is the code that I am using (I'm on Mac OS X 10.9):

```
find . \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.avi' \) -print0 | 
    xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/\./_/g'
```

I read up on two solutions, both which have not worked.

I first I added the following to my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export LC_CTYPE=C 
export LANG=C
```

This caused the same error, so then I tried using:

```
LC_ALL=C sed ...
```

and this did not work, I received this error:

```
xargs: LC_ALL=C: No such file or directory
```

Any other suggestions? I'm quite new to shell.

**EDIT:** This is what I am trying to accomplish:

I am trying to go through a directory and replace the underscores in the file names to dots.

Example:

random_movie.mp4 should be random.movie.mp4

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to do? That will remove `.` from _the contents_ of the file. If successful it will damage your videos. Are you trying to rename them?

Comment: yep @terdon , I'm only trying to rename. In no way would I want to be removing underscores from the contents of the file itself.

Comment: I think your sed options are around the wrong way - that will change dots to underscores.

Comment: OK, then do not run that command. The `sed` is being run on the files themselves and the `-i` means "edit files in place" which means that it will be run on the actual files and not on the file names printed by `find`. I'm not sure what that did to your movie files but it very likely changed the data of any that matched `.`. Please [edit] your question and explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: "illegal byte sequence" what command?

Comment: @terdon thank you for the feedback, I have updated the question with what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `-exec` here:

```
find . \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.avi' \) \
    -exec sh -cf 'IFS=._
    for f do d=${f%/*} f=${f##*/}
    [ -n "${f##*_*}" ] && continue
    set -- $f 
    printf "%s\n" "mv \\" "$d/$f \\" "$d/$*"
    done' find.rename.shc {} +
```

As written this only prints the command it will execute if you go through with it. For example, running the above on my `.../media/Videos` directory prints some of the following:

```
mv \
/mnt/bcache/media/Videos/TV/Adventure_Time/Adventure_Time.s05e37.The_Box_Prince.mp4 \
/mnt/bcache/media/Videos/TV/Adventure_Time/Adventure.Time.s05e37.The.Box.Prince.mp4
mv \
/mnt/bcache/media/Videos/TV/Adventure_Time/Adventure_Time.s05e38.Red_Starved.mp4 \
/mnt/bcache/media/Videos/TV/Adventure_Time/Adventure.Time.s05e38.Red.Starved.mp4
```

In order to go through with it you'd need to change:

```
...
set -- $f
printf "%s\n" "mv \\" "$d/$f \\" "$d/$*"
...
```

...to just...

```
...
set -- $f; mv "$d/$f" "$d/$*"
...
```

In general you should avoid passing filenames and similar over a pipe because when you do so you lose the the delimiters to the head and tail of the filename - it ceases to be an argument and becomes instead a sequence of bytes in a stream. The `-exec` option to `find` enables you to retain those delimiters in a child process of the running `find` process. With `+` it acts like `xargs` - execing the specified child process only as often as necessary to avoid an `ARGMAX` condition.

Regarding the `sed` problem - you might try:

```
LC_ALL=C xargs sed ...
```

That should at least avoid `xargs` interpreting the environment variable declaration as an argument. It will not help you to edit any filenames, though.

A last note - the issue you mention is generally caused by an incomplete multi-byte sequence occurring in pattern space. POSIX specifies that `.` cannot match *part* of a character - and so `.*` loses its meaning in that context. Forcing the `C` locale should resolve it - but another option for clearing hold/pattern spaces with a GNU `sed` is the `z` command.